# Bitfields in Scapy

Tags: python, protocols, scapy, packet

I've created a new packet type:

```
class goober(Packet):
    fields_desc=[
        Bitfield("alpha",5,3),
        ByteField("bravo",100),
        Bitfield("charlie",3,0)
    ]
```

This throws an error when sending.
But when I reorder as follows, it works:

```
class goober(Packet):
    fields_desc=[
        Bitfield("alpha",5,3),
        Bitfield("charlie",3,0),
        ByteField("bravo",100),
    ]
```

Problem is, I really need the first form.  Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?  Can you point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply must keep using BitField until you make a multiple of 8.

```
class goober(Packet):
    fields_desc=[
        BitField("alpha",0,3),
        BitField("bravo",100, 8),
        BitField("charlie",0,5)
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  The first mistake I made was the order of default value and bitfield width.   After I fixed that, and followed your suggestion, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Seems like correct handling of the first form would be a reasonable enhancement to Scapy.  Looks like Scapy is not well-maintained, even though it's a great tool.

Comment: No the first form isn't easy to implement, and just because you didn't make it work on your first try it doesn't mean that it's not maintained :(